# luigi tasks have conflicting pip dependencies

Tags: python, luigi

I have a luigi pipeline where some `luigi.Task`s have conflicting pip dependencies. This causes issues because those tasks are part of the same pipeline (i.e. one task requires the other). I would not want to create separated pipelines as I would not be able to inspect the full pipeline in the scheduler anymore. What are the best practices in this case?

**Example**: You have two python packages each defining a `luigi.Task`.
However `packageA` needs a different version of a library than `packageB`:

`packageA/task1.py` requires `mypackage==1.0.0`
`packageB/task2.py` requires `mypackage==0.9.0`

Let's say the pipeline is:
`task1 -> task2 -> wrappertask`

This is an issue as in `task2` I have to import `task1` in order to define the `requires` method:

```
# packageB/task2.py, needs mypackage==0.9.0

from task1 import Task1 # cannot do this as I would need mypackage==1.0.0

class Task2(luigi.Task):
   id = luigi.Parameter()

   def requires(self):
       task1.Task1(id=id)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run luigi with the local scheduler, all scheduling and task execution occurs in a single python process. So, any python package imported into the global namespace stays present and new import statements for that package will be ignored. You also have to know that luigi instantiates all task classes once, but calls the requires() and output() methods of each task multiple times during scheduling and task execution.

So, you only want to import the troubling package into the local namespace of the task method where you use it. Be sure that the package in its two versions is available on the PYTHONPATH, e.g. as pack1 and pack2 so that you can use an import statement like:

```
...
    ...
    import pack1 as pack
```